# showing some text in compiling that i am not able to understand

Tags: c, powershell, visual-studio-code

Why is my compiler showing this before executing the code?

```
cd "c:\...\myprojectdir\"; if ($?) { gcc a.c -o a } ; if ($?) { .\a }
```

[image: Terminal screenshot]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Probably the PowerShell command is generated by Visual Studio Code. The command compiles and runs your program with some error checking, e.g. run the program only if the compilation step was successful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please [don't show images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question), copy-paste text as *text* into your questions.

Comment: As for the "problem", it's not the compiler that outputs that text. It's the VSCode Code runner plugin, which executes that command-line in a terminal to build and run your command.

Comment: VS Code is not a compiler. It is an editor with some extra features. For your convenience it calls the compiler for you and executes the program afterwards. That is what you see.

Comment: what do you expect the command to be to compile and run the code

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that's not from the compiler. That's the PowerShell command that VSCode executes to compile and run your program.

The command changes the current work directory, compiles your program using `gcc`, then executes the compiled program.

It makes no sense to try to compile the program if the `chdir` failed. And it makes no sense to run the program if its compilation failed. As such, the command skips subsequent steps once an error occurred. This is done by checking `$?`. `$?` indicates whether the program exited with a zero status (usually indicating success) or not (usually indicating an error).